# Storing a member variable from a const reference parameter

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing, constants, pass-by-reference

By value:

```
class Test {
private:
    HugeObject h; // Copy 1
public:
    void SetObject(HugeObject hugeObject) { // Copy 2
        h = hugeObject;                     // Copy 3
    }
}

// Somewhere else
Test t();
t.SetObject(HugeObject());
```

This is bad because three implicit copies are created. If I change the parameter of `SetObject()` to `const HugeObject& hugeObject`, it's also bad because I'd be storing something that will no longer exist outside that function's scope.

So, to prevent copying twice and storing invalid data, I can copy just twice instead:

```
void SetObject(const HugeObject& hugeObject) { 
    h = HugeObject(hugeObject); // Copy constructor
}
```

Is this a valid way of handling this situation or am I misunderstanding something? A silly optimization or not an optimization at all? Are there better ways, aside from storing a pointer?

Comment: Read on move constructors [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `h` first in the class, what you're actually doing is calling the object's *default constructor*, which is implicitly called upon creation of an object that doesn't use an explicit syntax; that is,

```
HugeObject h; // Calls default constructor implicitly.
HugeObject h2 = HugeObject(); // Still calls default constructor.
HugeObject ougeHobject = HugeObject(h); // Calls copy constructor.
h2 = ougeHobject; // calls HugeObject's operator=
```

The last part is what I'm really getting at. When you assign `h` to `hugeObject` in `SetObject`, you're actually using `HugeObject`'s `operator=`. This is *not* the same thing as construction. If `operator=` isn't defined by a class, then the C++ implementation synthesizes it; this default works by assigning each member of the right-hand-side object of a basic type (`double`, for instance,) to the corresponding member on the left-hand-side object. For class types stored as variables of `hugeObject,` their corresponding `operator=`s are called.

To answer the question directly now, if you'd like to limit the copies you make, just assign h to a reference of `hugeObject` in `SetObject`, as both have already been instantiated:

```
void SetObject(const HugeObject& hugeObject) {
    h = hugeObject;
}
```

Although technically out of scope, the `const HugeObject&`'s values are copied via `HugeObject`'s `operator=` to `h`. This does not implicitly construct a new object, as both have already been instantiated; again, it just calls `operator=`.

Comment: Thanks, this and the other answers have led me to realize the misunderstandings I was making. Just to be sure: is assigning a const reference a valid practice, or kind of hacky?

Comment: @idlackage, I see no reason why assigning to a const reference would be hacky. It's just copying the data, essentially.

Answer (score 2):

> This is bad because three implicit copies are created.

Actually, only one copy happens in that situation. The `HugeObject()` temporary is constructed in-place as the argument `hugeObject`, and then it is copied into `h` from there.

> If I change the parameter of SetObject() to `const HugeObject& hugeObject`, it's also bad because I'd be storing something that will no longer exist outside that function's scope.

That's not accurate either - you're still copying into `h`, you're not storing a reference to it. That would save you a copy in the case of:

```
HugeObject h;
t.SetObject(h); // copy from h into t.h, no copy necessary
                // into the argument of SetObject()
```

Taking `hugeObject` by `const&` is the best way to do it in C++03. If you have access to a C++11 compiler, and your `HugeObject` is efficiently movable, you should additionally add an rvalue overload:

```
void setObject(HugeObject&& hugeObject) {
    h = std::move(hugeObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the object during construction?  Then you get the original creation and a copy.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Huge 
{
public:
    Huge() { cout << "constructor\n"; }
    Huge(const Huge & h) { cout << "copy\n"; }
    Huge & operator = (const Huge & h) { cout << "assignment\n"; return *this; }
};

class Holder
{
    Huge h;
public:
    Holder(const Huge & h_) : h(h_) {};
};

int main()
{
    Huge bar;
    Holder foo(bar);
}
```

Output:

```
constructor
copy
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d737eecdf0c00fbe)